# ORACLE 10g number datatype

Tags: oracle10g

I created a table called employees with one column named salary with data type NUMBER(11) 
and then I entered a value into salary of 12345678901
but in output it values shows like this 1.2345E+10.

Can anyone explain me what this is exactly?

Answer (score 3):

It is the [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) of the number. You may take a look at [this article](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i16209) about numeric data types in Oracle.

Comment: @Bhavana, the way you thank an answerer is to accept their answer. It's about time you started doing this.